# TypeError: cannot set property 'value' of null Autocomplete form google maps

Tags: forms, autocomplete

If I fill in my input field "Adresse automatisch ausfüllen:" my route and click enter so i have a js error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

I tried it already with ... = null; but I have the same error.

Here my JS Code:

```
<script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
```

An here my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <div class="form-row field_text">
                    <label for="veranstaltungsgelaende" class="required">Adresse automatisch ausfüllen:</label><br>
                    <input onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"id="autocomplete" class="input_text">
                    Geben Sie hier die komplette Adresse ein: (z.B: Rathausstraße 61 52222 Stolberg )
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="six columns b0">
                <div class="form-row field_text">
                    <label for="veranstaltungsgelaende" class="required">Veranstaltungsgelände Name*:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="veranstaltungsgelaende" name="veranstaltungsgelaende" class="input_text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row field_text">
                    <label for="plz" class="required">PLZ *:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="plz" name="plz" class="input_text">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="six columns b0">
                <div class="form-row field_text">
                    <label for="strasse" class="required">Straße *:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="route" disabled="true" name="strasse" class="input_text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row field_text">
                    <label for="ort" class="required">Ort *:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="ort" name="ort" class="input_text">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="twelve columns b0">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn_green right">Speichern und zur Übersicht</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
        Google Maps
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here my Testing Page:

http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/veranstaltungsort-erstellen.html

I try this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=de-DE

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need use all fields with correct elements id. Or set hidden fields for no need elements

```
<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
                                 disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
                                             disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
                                             disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
                                 id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
                                 disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
                                             id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any latecomers like me facing the similar issue, in below section remove the code that you do not need. For example if you don't have the country section in your form simply remove the `country: 'long_name'` from the code below.

```
var componentForm = {
      street_number: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      country: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };
```